# How do I embed a google calendar into my GWT App?

Tags: gwt

I am attempting to build a simple prototype in GWT using the google calendar where users can see the calendar entries of all the other users in their department and make new entries onto the calendar. I am looking for some good resources to help get me started.

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
1)http://code.google.com/p/gwt-cal/
2)http://code.google.com/p/ftr-gwt-library/